# Trigger function onclick when loading HTML from external source

Tags: reactjs

I'm loading HTML from an externally provided JSON file.  There are links in the the HTML that are currently being parsed using ReactHTML.

```
      {FAQdata.FAQdata.questions.map((question, index) =>
        <div className="question-container" key={index} id={"question-"+index}>
          <h3 className='font-weight--semi-bold'>{question.question}</h3>
          <p>{ReactHtmlParser(question.answer)}</p>
        </div>
      )}
```

My client wants me to add analytics functions that trigger when the link is clicked.  I'm trying to figure out how to add an event to this content which is not being loaded via React.

Some things I tried:
1) Adding a script tag to react targeting the link (produces an error)
2) Adding the event inline to the JSON file (also produces an error)

Any ideas about the cleanest way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By reading react-html-parser docs(cool library btw), you can wrap your parsed html with Provider and then with the transform function you can return your own react components Button with your Consumer.

```
  import React from "react";
  import ReactHtmlParser, {
    processNodes
  } from "react-html-parser";
  import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";


const {Provider, Consumer} = React.createContext();

function transform(node, index) {
  if (node.type === "tag" && node.name === "button") {
    return (
      <Consumer>
        {onClick => (
           <Button onClick={onClick} variant="contained" color="primary" key={index}>
           {processNodes(node.children, transform)}
          </Button>
        )}
      </Consumer>
    );
  }
}
const options = {
  decodeEntities: true,
  transform
};

const html = `<h1>Transform Example</h1>
<button type="button">this is button</button>
`;

function App({FAQdata}) {
  const handleClick = () => console.log('click');
  return(
   <Provider value={handleClick}>
    {FAQdata.FAQdata.questions.map((question, index) => (
      <div className="question-container" key={index} id={"question- 
        "+index}>
        <h3 className='font-weight--semi-bold'>{question.question}</h3>
        <p>{ReactHtmlParser(question.answer)}</p>
      </div>
     )}
    </Provider>
  ) ;
}
```

See working [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-html-parser-6zuv4)

originally taken from [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/2y8wqoqoy)

Comment: Ah that looks sweet, thanks for finding that. I'll give it a try in the next few days.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some snippets that I used, mostly the same as Gadi's example above

```
function linkClick(e, text) {
    var linkEvent = document.createEvent('customEvent');
    linkEvent.initCustomEvent('linkClick', true, true, {
        linkName: text //set to the name of the button or link, ex- 'play-again', 'continue'
    });
    document.body.dispatchEvent(linkEvent);
}

function transform(node, index) {
    if (node.name === "a") {
        var text = node.children[0].data;
        var href = node.attribs.href
        return ( <
            a onClick = {
                (e) => linkClick(e, text)
            }
            href = {
                href
            } > {
                text
            } <
            /a>
        );
    }
}

return ( < Provider > {
        FAQdata.FAQdata.questions.map((question, index) => ( <
            div className = "question-container"
            key = {
                index
            }
            id = {
                "question-" + index
            } >
            <
            h3 className = 'font-weight--semi-bold' > {
                question.question
            } < /h3> <
            p > {
                ReactHtmlParser(question.answer, options)
            } < /p> <
            /div>
        ))
    } 
    </Provider>
)
```